# Creating multiple pdf files using html2pdf

Tags: php, pdf, while-loop, tcpdf, html2pdf

I am quite new to html2pdf, so have been finding it difficult to create multiple invoices in a loop with:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');
while ( $MyRows = mysql_fetch_array($MyQuery) ) {
            include(dirname(__FILE__).'mypdf.php');
            $content = ob_get_clean();
            try
            {
                $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'en');
                $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fitpage');
                $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
                $Filename = "INV".$mem_id.".pdf";
                $html2pdf->Output($Filename, 'F');
            }
            catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
                echo $e;
                exit;
            }
}
```

But what happening is that script only generate one pdf for only first record perfectly as per my design and then sometimes, it shows errors like:

```
File : html2pdf\_class\parsingHtml.class.php
Line : 117
HTML code invalid, a tag is closed too many times: <td>
HTML : ...> </nobreak> </page>...
```

And sometimes, it just echoes the content of my included design as I have created it for the number of times mysql records are in while loop, but still only one pdf is generated.

Comment: I would recommend to convert your mypdf.php to the function that return html file and call that function in a loop instead of looping `include`. Your way is too tricky :-)

Comment: and if you are sure about that file quolity you can try to add `ob_start();` right before `include` line to see if first file was generated by `mypdf.php` only

Comment: Perfect mate, It did the work. Thanks for the function suggestion as well, but I think that both would be same things.